# Query using play framework brings back related tables without me asking

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I've got the following models in Play Framework.

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends Model {

  @Id
  public Long id;
  public String name;
  public List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();

}

@Entity
public class Child extends Model {

  // Entity 2
  @Id
  public Long id
  public String name;
  @ManyToOne
  public Parent parent;

}
```

Executing the following query gives me more information than I need.

```
 toJson(Child.find.all());
```

As an example, I get all children as well as their parents and parent's attributes and any other adjoining information.

I've tried setting the `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`, but it doesn't make a difference.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ebean has built in JSON support and you can use that if you want exact control over the parts of the object graph to include in JSON:

```
JsonContext jsonContext = Ebean.json();
JsonWriteOptions options = JsonWriteOptions.parsePath("id,name");
String json = jsonContext.toJson(list2, options);
```

And alternatively you can apply PathProperties to both the query and json like:

```
PathProperties pathProperties = PathProperties.parse("id,name");
query.apply(pathProperties);
// fetch only id and name
List<App> list3 = query.findList();

// json output only id and name
JsonWriteOptions options2 = new JsonWriteOptions();
options2.setPathProperties(pathProperties);
String json2 = jsonContext.toJson(list3, options2);
```

Note that Ebean 4.3 had it's json support refactored to use Jackon core for parsing and generation (so it's using Jackson under the hood). You are using Play so currently stuck on an old version of Ebean so instead of using query.apply() you'd use pathProperties.apply(query) I think.

Regarding @JsonIgnore ... obviously different use cases require different JSON which is why this feature exists in Ebean (when you get a use case that needs to include parent like)

```
PathProperties pathProperties = PathProperties.parse("id,name,parent(id,name)");
...
```

Comment: That looks really good, I'll have to try it when I get back to the Play project.

Answer (score 2):

Jackson's toJson() method always fetches all data while serializing Ebean's objects, so it can be real `performance killer`, that was discussed my proposition is using some dedicated object (not stored in DB) and filling it only with required data from 'original' object.

Check other answer, [which describes this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717035/1066240).

Answer (score 0):

I simply opted for the `@JsonIgnore` annotation.