# Play Framework: Use XML file as Model data source?

Tags: xml, playframework

I am relatively new to the Play framework, so I apologize if this has been asked. I have searched for an answer to no avail.

I am creating a simple web application to allow clients to configure data on a server via the remote browser. The employer would like this data to reside in a simple XML file instead of one of the supported databases like H2. Is this possible? Or, will I end up serializing from an in-memory DB?

I have the application working with H2; but I am stumped as to how to create an XML-based  Model-class so that I can use it in the Play Framework just like a database. Is there a way to create a class that will behave like "Model"; yet consume and write its data to an XML file instead of a database?

Comment: As an alternative to trying to make it seamlessly look like a database, have you considered just using [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialise your model class to XML and write the content to disk?

Comment: Have you read [How to convert Play Framework Models into XML and JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14810068/1212960)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do know how I could serialize the in-memory DB to an XML file when changes are made, but the employer wants the data to be in an XML file exclusively. Serializing will make a copy, but that copy will not be loaded into memory on the next start-up.  Is there a way for the XML file to be the actual DB that is both consumed and written?