# How to (un)marshall the value of the root element in a subclass

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm unmarshalling a complex object from XML to Java using JAXB. The problematic part of the XML looks like:

```
<product>
    <!-- SNIP -->
    <keywords>
        <keyword optionalAttribute="attrValue">Value</keyword>
        <keyword>Another value</keyword>
    </keywords>
</product>
```

I have a Java class for the parent object and for complex attributes, including keywords, with `javax.xml.bind.annotation.*` annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Product extends Model {

    // SNIP

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "keywords")
    @XmlElement(name = "keyword")
    public List<ProductKeyword> keywords;
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "keyword")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ProductKeyword extends Model {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "optionalAttribute")
    public String optionalAttribute;

    @XmlMixed
    public String keyword;

}
```

The `ProductKeyword.keyword` field needs to hold the value of the `<keyword>` element, which is the root element for the subclass. `@XmlMixed` doesn't seem to induce JAXB to attempt to unmarshall anything into that field.

I believe I need `@XmlValue`, but that annotation cannot be used on a subclass (unless possibly if the superclass is annotated with `@XmlTransient`.)

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Constraints:

- I can't change the format of the XML.
- I can't get rid of the `Model` superclass (required for persistence)
- I can't modify the superclass (from an external library)

Non-constraints:

- I can, if I need to, add extra fields to the parent or child Java classes.
- If I can get the values of the keywords into the class in any form or by any means, I can do whatever post-processing I need to get it in the right place/format.
- It doesn't have to be pretty.

Comment: are getters/setters needed here? I think they are.

Comment: I should explain the public attributes/lack of getters and setters. We use Play! framework which does encapsulation behind the scenes and explicit getters/setters are only meant to be used where you need to implement custom behaviour.
Not sure if you mean needed in general or needed for the JAXB annotations, but all the other JABX annotations work fine when placed on the field.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14810068/2834978). Seems you need `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Having tried that, it results in many `IllegalAnnotationException`s when I try to process a file. I also highly doubt it would make any difference if I could get it to work: as mentioned, every other `@Xml*` annotation works as expected when placed on the field, without that, so it would be strange if `@XmlMixed` was the only one that was sensitive to it.

Answer (score 1):

I trid in my code , you may try again !
Added this dependency in you Maven  or download the jar.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-RC1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Then you dont need to change your pojo any! just change the way  you unmarshal!
I store the xml in file , you can use in you way ,inputstream or any.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[]{Product.class}, new HashMap());
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("stand.xml").getInputStream();
        Product product= (Product) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
        System.out.println(product);
    }
```

[image: Success]

Comment: I believe this would solve my problem, but before I had a chance to try it, I've been told not to worry about fixing this particular issue at this time.
Thank you, nonetheless.